# Linq from list objects into one object with a list property

Tags: c#, string, linq, list

Im trying to use Linq to select the property **ProductColor** from a List of MyObject into the property **AllProductColors**

```
 public class MyObject
 {
    public string ImgUrl { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductColor { get; set; }
 }

 public class ObjectToSelectInto
 {
    public string ImgUrl { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public List<string> AllProductColors { get; set; }
 }

 //*** CREATING EXAMPLE ***///
 List<MyObject> MyObjectList = new List<MyObject>();
 ObjectToSelectInto destinationObject = new ObjectToSelectInto();
 //I can do it like this, but then I 
 //  would have to do this for every list item, not good!
 destinationObject.AllProductColors = 
 MyObjectList.Select(x => x.ProductColor).toList();

 //*** This fails ***///
 destinationObject = MyObjectList.Select( x =>
     new destinationObject {
     AllProductColors = x.ProductColor.ToList(),
     ImgUrl = x.ImgUrl.First().toString(),
     ProductName = x.ProductName .First().toString() 
 }
```

I want it to be like this.

**destinationObject has a list with elements where one color equals one element.**

Comment: Don't quite understand what you're attempting, but it sounds like SelectMany might be the right call to use?

Comment: what the point of this ? `x.MaterialColor.ToCharArray(0,x.MaterialColor.Length)` your string is already a char array ?

Comment: @Selman22 No point at all.. ? Just experimenting, trying to get a grip of the results produced.

Comment: Was it really that unclear?

Comment: yes, please explain your problem more clear.and tell us the expected result.I'm trying to understand you but still I don't understand what do you want exactly

Comment: Fair enough I'M updating the question

Comment: @8bitcat do you want to get all letters of your colors into a string list ? like `"G","R","A","Y","B","L","U","E"` etc ?

Comment: This question makes no sense at all. You're doing a lot of things that don't make sense: `x.ProductName.Select(y => y).ToString()` is just the same as `x.ProductName` It may be helpful if you just show the two class definitions and a before and after of what you're trying to do

Comment: @Kenneth yes it doesn't make sense but it's not the same with x.ProductName, it's completely a different thing, like `"System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator2[System.Char,System.Char]"`  calling `ToString` doesn't join the characters. It returns the type name

Comment: Updating as you comment

Comment: @Selman22 You're right, I missed that. That being said, I don't think that's the result he's after either :-)

Comment: You definitely need to post the class definitions. The question is confusing.

Comment: @Selman22 Did you get it know?

Comment: @8bitcat  much better but still not clear.Do you want to ONE destinationObject of list of destinationObject(s) ? and do you want to group your MyObjects by ImageUrl or Productname ?

Comment: @Selman22 i want obly one destination object. No need to group I think pick the first Productname they will always be the same.. Imgurl doesnt matter.. Pick the first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put your first query that you tried into second like this:

```
 destinationObject = MyObjectList.Select(x =>
        new ObjectToSelectInto()
        {
           AllProductColors = MyObjectList.Select(y => y.ProductName).ToList(),
           ImgUrl = x.ImgUrl,
           ProductName = x.ProductName
       }).First();
```

Comment: Feck why didnt I think of that.. !! Good one!!